# Creating a deadline based on criteria

Tags: python, pandas, select

With the datetime data below I would like to set a "deadline" relative to the 'Date' column. In essence, the deadline should be 2 Business Days from the time of the "Date". However there are some specific criteria, which are below:

If a 'Date' is in Holidays or on a weekend, then the deadline should be the next 2 business day at 17:00 hours.

If a 'Date' is on Monday-Friday, not a holiday, AND the hour of the 'Date' is between 0-8, then the deadline should be the next non-holiday, business day at 17:00 hours

If a 'Date' is on Monday-Friday, not a holiday, AND the hour of the 'Date' is between 9-17, then the deadline should be the next 2 non-holiday, business day at the same time.

If a 'Date' is on Monday-Friday, not a holiday, AND the hour of the 'Date' is between 18-23, then the deadline should be the next 2 non-holiday, business day at 17:00 hours

Below is the data:

```
import datetime

Holidays = [date(2018,1,1),date(2018,1,15),date(2018,2,19),date(2018,3,9)]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2018-01-01 18:47','2018-01-08 06:11','2018-01-12 10:05','2018-02-10 09:22','2018-02-20 14:14','2018-03-08 16:17','2018-03-25 17:35'],
                   'Weekday': [0,0,4,5,1,3,6],
                   'Hour': [18,6,10,9,14,16,17]})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

The result should be as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2018-01-01 18:47','2018-01-08 06:11','2018-01-12 10:05','2018-02-10 09:22','2018-02-21 14:14','2018-03-08 16:17','2018-03-25 17:35'],
               'Deadline': ['2018-01-03 17:00','2018-01-09 17:00','2018-01-17 10:05','2018-02-13 17:00','2018-02-23 14:14','2018-03-13 16:17','2018-03-27 17:00']})
```

Comment: What have you tried? What results did you get?

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is a platform to help people who are stuck with a programming question, not a coding service. Please post what you have tried so far